# After replacing one fragment in viewpager another fragment shows blank

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have two fragment named homeFragment and TopBlankFragment in MainActivity .
I want to pass data from mainActivity to homefragment . I passed data succesfully using bundle and replce home fragment . but the problem is after replacing homefragment TopBlankFragment shows blank .

Here is my code of how i pass my data to homefragment from main activity:-

```
if (newText.length() > 0) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("searchKey", newText);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, homeFragment);

                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
```

Here is code for how i accept data in homeFragment :-

Bundle bundle = getArguments();

```
if (bundle != null) {



    String searchKey = bundle.getString("searchKey");

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Searchkey " + searchKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textView.setText(searchKey);

}
```

but the main problem is the topBlankFragment shows blank .
Here is my viewpagerAdapter :-

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();


    public void addFragments(Fragment fragment,String titles)
    {
        this.fragments.add(fragment);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);
    }


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }



    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        fragments.remove(0);
        fragments.add(0, fragment);
        tabTitles.remove(0);
        tabTitles.add(0,"Home Fragment");

        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;

    }


}
```

Here is my Mainactivity.xml:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tanvir.testmaterialtablayout.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <include

                android:id="@+id/tolbarlayoutinmainactivity"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am searching solution for these whole days . But didn't find any suitable solution .

Comment: Did you use replaceFragment method?

Comment: Have you tried just starting over with a ViewPager exmaple/sample project in Android Studio?  Or at least looking at it to see how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this problem with viewpager.. Viewpager have some options to creare fragment. So if you set view pager offscreenpagelimit 1, in that case it will always create new fragment. So the data u brining from activity may lost 2nd time any show you blank fragment.

I suggest you too also put the code of activity class..

Answer (score 0):

First things first you dont have homeFragment and TopBlankFragment in MainActivity, your MainActivity has tablayout and Viewpager in it and viewpager has fragments homeFragment and TopBlankFragment. Now make sure you are not using same Resource ids in homeFragment layout as TopBlankFragment layout as it causes problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here,

*fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, homeFragment);*

You are replacing the viewPager itself with the homeFragment.

You should update the adapter which inflates the viewpager with fragments(including homeFragment)

So, just replace the homeFragment in the adapter with new homeFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Your **adapter** for the ViewPager works fine. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Use below technique to pass data within fragments

Send data

```
public static HomeFragment newInstance(String arg1) {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(KEY_OF_DATA_ARG, arg1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Receive data

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String argData = getArguments().getLong(KEY_OF_DATA_ARG);
}
```